# Wordpress category loop offset possible?

Tags: php

I have been on this for a while now and haven't really come across a solution to filter the posts on a category page using a sort of offset in php.

There are plugin for posts and pages but I am trying to achieve this with pure php and specifically for a category page.

Scenario example:
A blog with 7 posts, setting the offset to say 3 would begin the loop on the category page to only show (Post4, Post5, Post6, Post7) and NOT (Post1, Post2, Post3).

I am wondering if this would be possible at all and be dynamic enough to apply to all categories without the need to specifically identify which posts to exclude via id numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'offset' parameter does what you want. I've written this hack, it should help you...

```
<?php
    //The third parameter corresponds to action priority,
    //set it to change the order of execution in case of a conflict
    add_action('pre_get_posts', 'the_modified_loop', 10);

    function the_modified_loop($query){
        //Remove 'is_admin' if you want the code to run for the backend category archive page
        if(!is_admin() && $query->is_category()){
            $query->set('offset', 3);
        }
    }
?>
```

Let me know if it worked!

Comment: I didn't know if there was a way, should I place this right into the category loop? (I am a noob)

Comment: Nope... put it in the `functions.php` file...

Comment: It works perfect, just one thing though it is conflicting with "list category posts" plugin which also displays content with an offset. it seems to altering their offsets also. is there a way to keep it from altering their outputs?

Comment: Do you need that plugin at all? You could set the priority of my action in a way that it runs after or before that plugin.

Comment: Btw, I've edited my code to include a very important check, please note it.

Comment: There would be a lot of recoding to be done if I replace that plugin which outputs different offsets of the same loop in different areas of the page. I would consider switching it out later on but for now would there be a way to execute this script after that plugin runs?

Comment: Yeah, just set a very high priority so that my code runs after that plugin. Read this for help: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action

Comment: i tried with the updated code seem to be getting: Fatal error: Call to undefined method WP_Query::is_admin()

Comment: To avoid the error I tried removing is_admin() && from the script is then causing another error: Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Query could not be converted to string

Comment: OK got it to work now. just playing with the priority as it seems 10 is not doing it. still conflicting with the other plugin.

Comment: The code above works if there is only one loop on the page.  In my case I converted a category into a page with multiple widgetized areas which contain related posts with different offsets.  Unfortunately this seems to alter the source which affects my other widgets and displays the same information in all areas. Hope this helps others who dont have a unconventional setup like mine.

Comment: thanks for your help on this one you've answered my question above, but It seems my questions has evolved into a more complex question lol

Comment: Thanks for accepting! Sorry I couldn't get back to those errors you've posted. Is Admin is required so that you're code runs only on the front end. Try removing it, and check if the backend categories post displays normally. Is the error gone?

Comment: no problem, I removed the admin part and it ended up working correctly again displaying the posts.  Its just affecting other plugins.  I think my approach should be a little different as in trying to sort category listing by date then excluding the first X number of post from list.

Comment: I've edited my answer with a minor change, check it or you'll end up my function affecting your categories archive in the backend as well! ;)

Comment: Also, if there are multiple loops on your page, add the action right before the loop starts, and put `remove_action('pre_get_posts', 'the_modified_loop')` right after that loop ends.

Comment: I've added it to my archives.php file right around the loop.  I've updated the code above, is this correct? I think I may have it wrong as the other plugins have returned to normal but no effect on the primary category loop.

Comment: Please create a paste on pastebin.com and give me the link

Comment: here it is on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/BMCbueiP

Comment: I don't see anything wrong over there... Just move the actual function to `functions.php`, and add the priority to remove action as well...

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to check [`$query->is_main_query()`<sup>*Codex*</sup>](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_main_query):

```
<?php
//The third parameter corresponds to action priority,
//set it to change the order of execution in case of a conflict
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'the_modified_loop', 10);

function the_modified_loop($query){
    //Remove 'is_admin' if you want the code to run for the backend category archive page
    if( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() && $query->is_category() ) {
        $query->set( 'offset', 3 );
    }
}
?>
```